# p:poll calling growl twice

Tags: java, primefaces, growl

In my code I have a xhmtl page that has a p:poll (primefaces). Every 5 sec it updates the panelMap (my panel). When the map is updated it has to show 3 messages with growl, the problem is that it shows more 3, then I get 6 messages. And I tryied many diff. ways and couldnt resolve.

view

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/Layout.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

    <title>Monitoramento</title>
    <f:metadata>

        <f:event listener="#{gadoBean.obterPosicaoTag}" type="preRenderView" />
    </f:metadata>

    <ui:define name="corpo">
        <script
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="mykey"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
        <h:form prependId="false">
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <p:poll interval="5" listener="#{gadoBean.obterPosicaoTag}"
                    update="panelMap" />
                <p:button value="Adicionar Pasto" outcome="/area/criarArea.xhtml" />
                <p:button value="Mudar animal de pasto"
                    outcome="/propriedade/mudarAnimal.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:panel id="panelMap" header="Monitoramento"
                footer="clique sobre o pasto desejado para obter suas informações"
                style="margin-top:30px;margin-left:230px;width:700px;max-width:100%;height:450px;max-height:100%">
                <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="false" sticky="true" />

                <p:gmap id="mapa" center="#{gadoBean.center}" zoom="17"
                    model="#{gadoBean.mapa}" type="HYBRID"
                    style="width:862px;height:400px;max-width:100%;max-height:100%">
                    <p:ajax event="pointSelect"
                        listener="#{gadoBean.aoSelecionarPonto}" update="growl" />
                </p:gmap>

            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: does it work ??

Comment: it didn't work :/

Comment: I found a solution! I took out this line at metadata <f:event listener="#{gadoBean.obterPosicaoTag}" type="preRenderView" /> because growl is updating when the method obterPosicaoTag is called. Then, it's being called twice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a life to your `growl`, so that the 3 three first messages disappear before 5 seconds, then when `p:poll` updates `panelMap` after 5 seconds, another 3 messages shows up, `life="4500"` (4500 milliseconds) :

```
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="false" sticky="true" life="4500" />
```